# Retrieve JSON POST Parameters in express node

Tags: node.js, express, postman, postman-pre-request-script

this is the first time I am using node js. I am sending post request through Postman. The problem is I am unable to get these params. It says undefined or empty

[image]

This is what I have tried so far

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));


// support encoded bodies
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});






app.post('/login',function(req,res){

    console.log('request =' + JSON.stringify(req.body))
    console.log(req.body);

    var user_name=req.body.user;
    var password=req.body.password;
    res.send(req.body);

    console.log("User name = "+user_name+", password is "+password);
    res.end("yes");
});
```

express version is 4.16.4

This is what appears on the console

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add your console logs please

Comment: did you send 'application/json' as content-type header?

Comment: What version of Postman are you using, that seems very old.

Comment: @NirLevy  I have updated my question

Comment: @BraveButter I have added the console log in my question

Comment: *I am sending post request through Postman* WHERE IS THE POSTMAN?

Answer (score 1):

set headers: `{"Content-Type": "application/json"}` in the request. Changing it will solve the problem.